# What is the time complexity for while loop inside a while loop?

Tags: c++

```
 int i = 0, j = A.size() - 1;
    while (i < j) {
        while ((i < j) && (A[i] % 2 == 0)) ++ i;
        while ((i < j) && (A[j] % 2 == 1)) -- j;
        swap(A[i], A[j]);
        i ++; 
        j --;
```

We can scan from both ends of the array, swap them if not in place. Why is the time complexity O(N) and not O(N*N)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can rewrite the code to make it clearer:

```
 int i = 0, j = A.size() - 1;
 while (i < j) {
   if (A[i] % 2 == 0) ++ i;
   else if (A[j] % 2 == 1) -- j;
   else {
     swap(A[i], A[j]);
     i++; 
     j--;
   }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

The complexity of the algorithm is O(N) because the number of operation will in any case will be j-i times only.

Here the inner loops for any iteration of outer loop will execute for j-i times.